# Clean screen of random images

Tags: objective-c, image, random

This is my first time posting something, first of all you got to know two things, I'm very rookie on objective-c and english is not my native language, so if you don't understand well please ask :)

Ok, I'm making an iPad app for my kid, so it consists of random sound and a random image on every tap. But after some taps the screen gets full of images so I want to know how to "clean" the screen after X taps.

Some code here:

```
- (void)oneFingerOneTap{


int randomNumber = arc4random() % 9 + 1;
int randX = arc4random() % 768 + 1;
int randY = arc4random() % 1004 + 1;

NSString *fileName = @"Sound";
NSString *ext = @".caf";
NSString *randString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", randomNumber];
NSString *completeSound = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@%@%@", fileName, randString, ext];

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], completeSound];

SystemSoundID soundID;
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];


AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);


self.imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(randX, randY, 60, 60)];
self.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"];
[self.view addSubview:self.imgView];




NSLog(@" %d", randX);

count++;
}
```

So I make a global int (count) to know how much taps done yet.

ps. I know the image isn't random at the time, it doesn't matter right now.

Again, how can I delete all the images done before?

I tried with `self.imgView.hidden = TRUE;` but it only hidden the last image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
 for (UIView *subVw in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([subVw isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [subVw removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: hey! that's works fine! really thanks, i cant vote up, i need more reputation, I will give you when I be able to :) thanks dude

Comment: removeAllSubviews will remove all the views from your screen that are in view hierarchy, I remember using that method, now I just noticed xcode complains when Im trying to call that method (maybe SDK version issue? not sure). the code above will remove the subviews type of UIImageView, so if you have a UIButton ,etc in your screen, they will remain on your screen. you can also set the tag of your UIImageView as a mark that this UIImageView should remain on screen or remove from screen when you X taps, in case you have another images along that you dont want to remove.

Comment: the code works just fine, the other person delete their answers lol, thanks a lot dude